# Install Gitlab Repository : Wordlists

Tags: debian

I want to install [this repository](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/wordlists) which is the repository of wordlists in Kali Linux but i dont find how to install it in my Debian machine.
The README file said to : "edit the file wordlist-symlinks and add the new file and symlink with the format path:symlink" I dont understand what does that mean ?

I have download the repo and launch multiple command like this : `python3 -m pipx install wordlists --inlude-deps`
And this : `sudo ln -sf /opt/wordlists:symlink /usr/share/wordlists`
to make the symlink to my file /usr/share/wordlists, but it does't work when i type : `wordlists` in my shell.

Can you help me to install this repo ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The README is instructions on how to contribute to the project, not on how to install the software.

Since it has a debian/ directory, this is the source for a Debian package. You need to build it like any other Debian package. Follow the instructions in the [Building Tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution thank you for your post.
To install the repo you a have to launch this commands :

Clone the repo :
`git clone https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/wordlists.git`

Change directory to the file download :
`cd wordlists/`

launch the build with this command :
`dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`

back to the subfile :
`cd ..`

and finaly install with :
`sudo dpkg -i name_of_packet.deb`